# Drag element until attribute contains text

Tags: java, selenium, drag-and-drop

I have this element :

```
<span class="iic-slider__handle" style="left: 0%; bottom: auto;">
```

I'm trying to drag this element to the right until the attribute style contains
"left: 30%".

something like this:

```
 while(!element.getAttribute("style").contains("30")) {
            actions.clickAndHold(this.handles.get(0)).
                    moveByOffset(1,0).
                    release().build().perform();
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the purpose of your test to validate the drag and drop functionality or are you just trying to move the element into a fixed position?  -  You can potentially use JS to set the final position but if that's not what you need can you please share your code so far? :-)

Comment: I'm trying to validate drag and drop functionality, see my edit

Comment: I do not know how actions work in loops but I am not sure you need to `release` each new iteration. Of course it depends on your particular UI but it might happen that when you release, your element returns back to the initial position.

Comment: Logic looks in your code OK - but so many "depends" (too many for comments!) - only way to really provide an answer (and not a guess) is to have a go and make sure it works before posting. Can you please provide an url to the page you're looking at or to a sample page that has the same control based on the technology you're using?

Comment: you may want to include more of the markup here.  I'd also output your current style attribute for each iteration to check...  but why not "actions.clickAndHold(element)?"  Not sure why you're using a handle there.